# Date-range in JDBC in query to Oracle database, in Java

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g

```java
String sql="select id from period where '"+systemDate+"' between startDate and endDate";
```

I need to execute this query and I am using Oracle 10g. I want to get the `id` which falls between these dates. Problem I am facing is in Oracle my date format is "dd-mon-yy" and `systemDate` is in format "yyyy-mm-dd". So is there any way to convert Java date to dd-mon-format or any other way to execute the above query?

Answer (score 2):

You should convert your java.util.Date to a java.sql.Date and use a PreparedStatement as shown below:

```
java.util.Date jStartDate = ...; //your "java" date object
java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(jStartDate.getTime());

java.util.Date jEndDate = ...;
java.sql.Date endDate = new java.sql.Date(jEndDate.getTime());

PreparedStatement p = connection.prepareStatement("select id from period where systemDate between ? and ?");
p.setDate(1, startDate);
p.setDate(2, endDate);
ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has date formatting classes.  `DateFormat` is the abstract parent class for these, `SimpleDateFormat`  [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)  is probably the one you want

```
SimpleDateFormat oracleStyle = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
String dString = oracleStyle.format(systemDate);
String sql="select id from period where '"+systemDate+"' between startDate and endDate";
```

I havent tested this.  The format call might need new string buffers as arguments, and my format string could be off, but this is the idea.  Read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Other Answers are now outdated. The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). These supplanted the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Write your SQL using parameters. Use `?` as a placeholder for the value to be passed in at runtime.

Use [text blocks](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378) for easier reading.

Never use the SQL command `BETWEEN` in date-time work. Spans of time are best defined using the *Half-Open* approach, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. In contrast, `BETWEEN` is fully closed, to include both endpoints. For example, a month starts on the first of the month and runs up to, but does not include, the first of the following month.

```java
String sql = """
        SELECT id_ 
        FROM event_ 
        WHERE NOT ( date_ < ? ) 
        AND date_ < ? 
        ;
        """ ;
```

You said:

> oracle my date format is "dd-mon-yy"

No, incorrect. A [`DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en//database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) column in Oracle database is *not* text. So it has no “format”.

You said:

> systemDate is in format yyyy-mm-dd.

In Java use date-time objects to hold date-time values. Date-time objects are not text, so they have no “format”.

If handed some text as your input date, parse as a [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object. Your specified format complies with ISO 8601 standard. That standard is used by default in the *java.time* classes for generating/parsing text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```java
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2024-01-01" ) ;
LocalDate end = start.plusMonths( 1 ) ; // Cover month of January of 2024.
```

Pass these objects as the values to be substituted for the `?` placeholders in our SQL statement.

```java
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , end ) ;
```